Are there ways to get crawl error data from Google Search Console
I have 100s of accounts to manage. I want to build an aggregated report of all the crawl errors for all my websites.
Is there a way to export this data for all my websites at once? I am looking for the data on the Pages tab under indexing with the title 'Why pages aren't indexed'
I tried using the Search Console API but it looks like crawl error reports have been deprecated
https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/5385049/can-no-longer-query-crawl-errors-via-api?hl=en

Getting crawl error data from Google Search Console for multiple accounts is a bit tricky now that the API no longer provides this specific information. While the Search Console API still works for other data, the “Why pages aren't indexed” tab isn't directly accessible via API.
Instead, you can use Google Sheets with add-ons like Keywords in Sheets to aggregate some of the data manually. Another workaround is to check your server logs or analytics from caching services like CloudFront, where some crawl error data might be reflected. It's not perfect, but it helps bridge the gap until a better solution comes along.
If you need to gather crawl error data across multiple Google Search Console accounts, unfortunately, direct access through the Search Console API is no longer possible for this specific data. However, you can use the Crawl Stats Report in Google Search Console, which provides a detailed view of how Googlebot crawls your site, including failed requests like 404s or server errors. While this isn’t a direct replacement for API access, it helps you monitor errors. For large-scale analysis, consider using third-party SEO tools that can automate data collection across multiple sites​.

You can try using the Keywords in Sheets extension for Google Sheets.
